# sys.argv ot working in coomanline argument

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have simple python script in which I am trying to pass argument.

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import subprocess, sys
 cmd = "aws s3 ls --profile sys.argv[0]"
 n = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
 a,b = n.communicate()
 print(a)
```

I tried it with below method but not working as well.

```
cmd = "aws s3 ls --profile ' + str(sys.argv) + '"
```

So when I hit

```
./myscript.py noc
```

It should get like

```
ln = "aws s3 ls --profile noc"
```

and proceed with next steps in script.

Comment: Nothing in your code is actually calling `sys.argv`. Is it something like this that you're looking for? `f"aws s3 ls --profile {sys.argv[1]}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with 
`ln = 'aws s3 ls --profile ' + str(sys.argv[1]) + ''`